# Type missing properties, but it doesn't?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two interfaces:

**dish-component.ts**:

```ts
    export interface DishComponent {
    componentId: string;
    componentQuantity: number;
}
```

**dish.ts**:

```ts
import { DishComponent } from 'src/app/interfaces/dish-component';

export interface Dish extends DishComponent {
    name: string;
    components: DishComponent[];
    totalCost: number;
}
```

I'm using Angular, in my component for dishes I try to create a Dish:

**dishes.component.ts**:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from 'src/app/interfaces/dish';
// other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dishes',
  templateUrl: './dishes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dishes.component.css']
})

export class DishesComponent {

  // other stuff

  myDish: Dish = {
    name: "myTestDish",
    components: [
      {
        componentId: "sdfsdf76sdf76",
        componentQuantity: 4,
      },

      {
        componentId: "dfh097fgj46j",
        componentQuantity: 4,
      },
    ],
    totalCost: 2354,
  };

  // other stuff
}
```

*myDish* yields the error:

> Type '{ name: string; components: { componentId: string; componentQuantity: number; }[]; totalCost: number; }' **is missing the following properties from type 'Dish'**: componentId, componentQuantity ts(2739)

**I don't understand, how is the properties componentId and componentQuantity missing? What am I doing wrong?**

Probably something obvious I'm missing, but I'm glad if you can point it out.

## Solution:

**Remove the extends in dish.ts**. The Dish extends DishComponent imply it needs to have all the properties DishComponent has.

Comment: `Dish` extends `DishComponent`, so it needs to have all the properties `DishComponent` has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the extends class u will see this is working as expected. Indeed DishComponent requires cmpId and cmpQt but u do not set it. U need or to specify or to remove which I assume will be the solution.

Extends is a keywoard that "copy" the following interface properties.

Comment: see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html :)